# jQuery Scroll to Bottom addClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve `navbar` to be fixed when scroll from bottom to top of  page. When we scroll from top to bottom position must be relative.

> I want to add the class when I scroll back to menu from bottom and
>   remove it at the end reaching the menu again.

I have tried with `scrollTop` with negative values but its not working me.

Thanks in Advance!.

[image: scrolldown-scrollup]

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $('nav').addClass("sticky");
    } else {
        $('nav').removeClass("sticky");
    }
});


$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > -200) {
        $('nav').addClass("sticky");
    } else {
        $('nav').removeClass("sticky");
    }
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
    height: 70px;
    background: #f00;
    position:relative;
}

nav.sticky {
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in 0s;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in 0s;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1049;
}

section {
    height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav></nav>

<section></section>
```

Comment: I would recommend to add the transition rules to the plain nav-tag, so they get triggered when the class changes

Comment: How? Can you post answer it with explanation

Comment: I did. Have a look at my answer. You can scroll down and up again. The class will be set correctly. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Manticore add the class when I scroll back to menu from bottom and remove it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
         $('nav').removeClass("sticky");

   } else {
      $('nav').addClass("sticky");
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
    height: 70px;
    background: #f00;
    position:relative;
}

nav.sticky {
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in 0s;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in 0s;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1049;
}

section {
    height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav></nav>

<section></section>
```

you have to save your ScrollTop Value and compare it!

Comment: Okay. But again I want to remove the class when reach the menu.

Comment: yes, it removes your class "sticky" if you scroll down

Comment: No. The class remains same place.

Comment: i edit the post and it works on my site. If you scroll down the class sticky will removed. If you scroll up it gets the class sticky

Comment: I want the class `sticky` to be removed when bottom to top scroll reach the menu.

Comment: I don't know how to remove added class at the end

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  let offs = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (Math.abs(offs) > 200) {
        $('nav').addClass("sticky");
    } else {
        $('nav').removeClass("sticky");
    }
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
    height: 70px;
    background: #f00;
    position:relative;
}

nav.sticky {
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in 0s;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in 0s;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1049;
}

section {
    height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav></nav>

<section>dawdwapjdawopidjawpio</section>
```

Works fine

Comment: No. You check the @Miche ans he answered correctly. but when we scroll from bottom to top at the end have to remove the `sticky`.

Comment: thats what my code does. what browser are you using?

Comment: maybe you did not even scroll down far enough? I'd recommend lowering the value to 20 or so

Comment: I don't  want to add the class when scroll top to bottom

Answer (score 0):

just detect the direction of scrolling by checking the `current scroll` value against the `last scrolled` value.

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var currentScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  
   if (currentScrollTop > lastScrollTop){
        $('#test').html(currentScrollTop +' scrolling down....');
        $('nav').removeClass("sticky");
   } else {
       $('#test').html(currentScrollTop +'  scrolling up');
       $('nav').addClass("sticky");
   }
  
   lastScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
    height: 70px;
    background: #f00;
    position:relative;
}

nav.sticky {
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in 0s;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in 0s;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1049;
}

section {
    height: 900px;
}

#test {position: fixed; bottom: 10px; left: 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav></nav>

<section></section>

<!-- for test -->
 <span id="test"></span>
```

Comment: You almost done. I want the class removed reverse side(top) while reaching the menu not at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

After the consolidated answers. I have found the right solution using those answers.

I just added the value `0` in another condition it helped me to achieve the desired result.

**Just see the result in green background.**

Thanks.

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var currentScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (currentScrollTop > lastScrollTop) {
        $('nav').removeClass("sticky");
    } else if (currentScrollTop == 0) {
        $('nav').removeClass("sticky");
    } else {
        $('nav').addClass("sticky");
    }

    lastScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
    height: 70px;
    background: #f00;
    position: relative;
}

nav.sticky {
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in 0s;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in 0s;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1049;
    background:green;
}

section {
    height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav></nav>

<section></section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Modify you Jquery like below, It will work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
            $('nav').addClass("sticky");
        } else {
            $('nav').removeClass("sticky");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this is incorrect beacuse the value is at the bottom of the page always > 200, you have to save your current ScrollTopValue

Comment: Not working for me. I need bottom to top scroll only